# Flask пагинация без sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pagination

У меня есть приложение на Flask с использованием БД MySQL. Запросы на сыром MySQL. Есть страница на которую выводятся новости. Хочу сделать что то типа пагинации или кнопку для динамической погрузки, "Показать ещё". Если что не ясно написал не серчайте.

```
app.py
@app.route('/')
def index():
 
    return render_template('index.html', menu=dbase.getMenu(), posts=dbase.getPostAnonce())

getsql.py

class SqlCon():
    def __init__(self, bd):
        self.__bd = bd
        self.__cur =bd.cursor()
    def getPostAnonce(self):
        try:
            sql = "SELECT id, title, posttext, url, `data` FROM z250wzqrec95yxzh.postnews ORDER BY `data` 
         DESC "
            self.__cur.execute(sql)
            res = self.__cur.fetchall()
            if res: return res
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print('Ошибка работы с таблицей sqlsite.postnews метод getPostAnonce'+str(e))
            return False
        return []
```

index.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{ super() }}

<h2>Новости охотничьего мира России</h2>
{% for p in posts %}
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
   Дата: {{ p.data.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ p.title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ p.posttext[:100]|striptags}}</p>
    <a href="{{url_for('showPost', allias=p.url)}}" class="btn btn-success">Читать новость</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать url_for.
Для того чтобы создать гиппер сылку на обьект находящися в вашем проекте.

Comment: Можно подробнее? как передавать данные о том какие выводить? Получится надо делать выборку по лимит? и в гет запросе передавать параметр?

Comment: Вы можете зделать так.
url = /help
{{url_for'{{ url }}'}}

Comment: Я не очень понимаю. О чем речь((

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1287192/edit)